# XMLHttpRequest blocked by CORS policy annotation @CrossOrigin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup' from origin 'https://mysuite.ru' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

```
http.cors().and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/manifest.json").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/logo192.png").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);




@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
public class AuthController {
```

Redirecting via nginx

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name   is my address.ru;

    ssl_certificate      C:/ssl/ip.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  C:/ssl/ip.key;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass        http://localhost:8080;
      proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

UPDATE

Request Headers:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If- 
Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length,Content-Range
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Yandex";v="21"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 YaBrowser/21.8.3.614 Yowser/2.5 
Safari/537.36
```

Add in nginx:

```
location / {
    
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
     #
     # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
     #
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
     #
     # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
     #
     add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
     add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
     add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
     return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
     add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
     add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
    }
    
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
```

No result yet

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `methods` attribute to `@CrossOrigin`. When used to annotate a method, the supported methods are the same as the ones to which the method is mapped, but since you are using it at the class level you might need to specify them as follows:

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600, methods = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST} ) // Just an example
```

Comment: how should it look like? ..... methods = "GET", "POST"); ?

Comment: I've edited my answer ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, for some reason this did not help me (

Comment: Can you please try adding the `Origin` header in your request with the origin domain of the request itself? Additionally, are you trying to do some redirect on the backend?

Comment: Yes, at the moment I am using nginx, I redirect listening from the domain and port 80 to 443 and from there to the spring application itself localhost: 8080

Comment: If I am not mistaken CORS does not allow redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your @CrossOrigin annotation with

```
 @CrossOrigin(value = "https://mysuite.ru", allowCredentials = "true")
```

Don't use "*" as an origin but "https://mysuite.ru".

Comment: For some reason this did not help me

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was mistakenly doing a post request on the front side to localhost